# Volume by Rotation Using Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, rotations

How to find the volume if the shown area is rotated around the $y$-axis?

The area will be bounded by $=^2+1$, $y=2x$ and $x=0$.

[image: This is the area, but I couldn't find the volume of it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $V_y=\pi\int_c^d x^2 dy$.

So, $V_{y_1}=\pi\int_0^2 \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2dy$ is the volume of cone, and the $V_{y_2}=\pi\int_1^2\left( y-1 \right)dy$ is the volume of a rotationally symmetric body given by a rotation of parabola $x^2=y-1$ around $y$-axis. Hence, desired volume is:

$$V_{y_1} - V_{y_2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with your instructions. The answer is /6, which I hope it's right.

Comment: You are welcome. I did not try to calculate, but will later for sure...
**EDIT:** I found $\frac{\pi}{6}$ as correct volume.

Comment: Thank you again for the confirmation!